# Load sections of a website at specific times

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, optimization

Hello stack overflow community,

I am struggling to get this website to load quickly.  It is a one page portfolio site running off the 'Simply' Theme available at Themeforest:

http://themeforest.net/item/simply-one-page-multipurpose-html-template/7788220?WT.ac=search_item&WT.oss_phrase=simply&WT.oss_rank=5&WT.z_author=AliA

With a video header and all of the other content below the header, we are looking at a 5 second load time.

What I am looking for is a way to load just the video header and navigation at first load, and after the video finishes loading and starts playing, the remaining content will start to load.

I am not all too familiar with Ajax or writing Javascript, but if I could get pointed in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated!

From what I've read so far, possibly the .load javascript might do the trick, but I have not found much information on it or where to start.

Answer (score 0):

`.load()` includes a callback (see [here](http://api.jquery.com/load/)) - so, assuming your content is all on the same domain, you just need to do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#div_where_you_want_to_load_the_video').load(
    '/path_to_video',
    '#video_container',
    function() {
      //load the rest
    }
  );
});
```

Make sure you have jQuery loaded first.